# Might the coronavirus be transmitted by packages shipped from China?

Tags: virus, infectious-diseases, epidemiology

There is currently [a coronavirus outbreak in China](https://www.ynetnews.com/article/H1I22Zh11I). I order many packages from China, mostly electronics parts. I see that I have dealt with distributors on Aliexpress from Wuhan, the coronavirus epicenter, and other affected cities.

**Is there any chance of coronavirus, or other commutable diseases, being transmitted via post?**